# VBA Syntax error using Dir having contentenation and wildcards

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through a series of files having the appearence

```
  Costs 2015-01 , Costs 2015-02, ..., Costs 2016-12
```

However using

```
YearNo = Year(Date)
path2 = Dir("C:\pathtofile\Costs " & YearNo & "-"& ?? & ".xlsx")
```

Gives syntax error for the expression for path2. 
What I expected that the expression would yield would be:

```
C:\pathtofile\Costs 2015-(all files having a two digit number after the "-").xlsx
```

(Or well, the file names Costs 2015-01... etc at least, since `Dir` only returns file name)

I've tried to use `& YearNo & -?? & ".xlsx"` and `& YearNo & "-??" & ".xlsx"` and `&YearNo -?? &".xlsx"` but none of them works. Does anyone have a clue regarding this?

EDIT: I'm using `YearNo` as the folder contains a bunch of files having *Costs 2014-...* expressions which I do not want to import. Also, using this technique I believe that the program needs to import less data come, for instance, 2022 when it only need to import the files for 2022, and not for 2015 up to 2022.

Comment: `path2 = Dir("C:\pathtofile\Costs " & YearNo & "-??.xlsx")` should work - do you get an error with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `??` is a litteral string and should be treated as such (and not as a variable). It belongs inside the `"`quotes`"`.

```
path2 = Dir("C:\pathtofile\Costs " & YearNo & "-??.xlsx")
```

Comment: Oh, I thought as it is a wildcard it "works" somewhat like a function, and not as a mere contanenation of a "constant" value. Will try this once I've finished my meeting